# marquee code working in chrome but not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

wants to stop marquee code on mouse over and start it on mouse out
but its working fine in chrome but not working in firefox

my code is:

```
<marquee direction="up" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
<h4>Writing</h4>
<p class="content">Get a professional resume written by experts</p><br/>
<h4>Certifications</h4>
<p class="content">Exhibit your skills to catch the eyes of recruiters</p>
</marquee>
```

Comment: [`marquee` is obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html)... And terrible.

Comment: marquee is an old tag that isn't supported by all browser

Comment: Try choosing alternatives, because W3.org deprecated this tag. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Comment: Since `marquee` is a visual effect, it is added in CSS level 3 as [CSS Marquee](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/) *(not fully browser compatible)*

Answer (score 4):

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; height:80px; overflow:hidden; display:block; border:solid 1px gray; padding:2px; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px;">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5" style="width:100%; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="javascript:this.setAttribute('scrollamount','0');" onmouseout="javascript:this.setAttribute('scrollamount','5');">
    Any text, images, divs, ...
    </marquee>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Marquee has been discouraged by W3C Standards. Maybe you can use javascript or jQuery effect to make it work. Check this link: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/
Hope this helps!

Comment: Marquee was not in any of the HTML specification, be it 4 or 5, it's a non standard property

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks Mr. Alien!

Comment: Even in 2018, Marquee is a very useful element. JS alternatives could eat up a lot of resources unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

following code worked in chrome and firefox both

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);this.stop();" OnMouseOut="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);this.start();" height="120px" scrollamount="2">testing scroll up </marquee>
```

Comment: Not working Firefox; because it isn't triggered start automatically.